# How to setup mail folder path in Yii2 framework

Tags: php, email, path, yii2

I have a yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced installed. There are three main folders - common, frontend, backend. The folder for emails is in common/mail folder. If I try to send email from frontend controller on register user it throws me an error:

> The view file does not exist:
> C:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\yii2\frontend/mail\emailVerify-html.php

Registration is generated via console command. But is obvious that the path to mail folder is wrong. I found a workaround to it via

```
\Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = '@common/mail/layouts/html';
\Yii::$app->mailer->textLayout = '@common/mail/layouts/text';
```

but it does not look very good. Is it possible to set it up in config file? Hope so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SO as I found out there is an option in config file named viewPath which is not mentioned in documentation.

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '587',
            'username' => 'your_username',
            'password' => 'your_password',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: It is mentioned in documentation. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-basemailer#$viewPath-detail

Comment: I meant this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing